# Passing form status data between parent and child components

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Using Angular 2, I have a long, complex form that I have split into one parent and two child components for easier management. The process works great until I need to keep track of the form status for validation. While data about the bound model can easily be transmitted via an @Input, I cannot figure out how to transmit data about the form itself.

Here's an example using pseudo-code:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <form #f="ngForm">
          <basic-details [exampleModel]="exampleModel"></basic-details>
          <advanced-details [exampleModel]="exampleModel"></advanced-details>
          <p>Form data: {{f.value | json}}</p>
        </form>
    `
})
export class ParentFormComponent {
    public exampleModel: ExampleModel = new ExampleModel();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'basic-details',
    template: `
        <input type="text" name="details" [(ngModel)]="exampleModel.details">
    `
})
export class BasicDetailsComponent {
    @Input() exampleModel: ExampleModel;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'advanced-details',
    template: `
        <input type="text" name="advanced" [(ngModel)]="exampleModel.advanced">
    `
})
export class AdvancedDetailsComponent {
    @Input() exampleModel: ExampleModel;
}
```

At the bottom of the form I am displaying the form values using a JSON pipe. `f.value` should display data about the "details" and "advanced" inputs. How do I pass information between the parent and child components so that the parent can keep track of the form status? Ideally this would work with both template driven and reactive forms.

Comment: The standard way is to store the data in a service that is accessible by all components.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, creating a service that the parent and child components share is a good solution. You can then make use of [FormArray](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) that can tell if all forms are valid.

Example of a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {
  private formArray: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

  addForm(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    this.formArray.push(formGroup);
  }

  allValid(): boolean {
    return this.formArray.valid;
  }

  anyDirty(): boolean {
    return this.formArray.dirty;
  }
}
```

In you ParentComponent you want to provide the service so that is will be shared only between the parent and its children.

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [FormService]
})
```

In your components you need to invoke `this.formservice.addForm(this.form);` after your form has been built.